# Is there an CKEditor Equivalent to WPF?

Tags: wpf, editor

WPF-Math is inactive, MathTex I could not use and I can not find a good control to use as an equation editor in my WPF application.

I'm trying to adapt the Math Editor project, but is not serving me well:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522345/OOP-in-the-Real-World-Creating-an-Equation-Editor

The editor of this project allows you to create equations, but makes editing difficult.

Comment: Do you want free solution?

Comment: There is definitely no CKEditor equivalent in WPF. The various WPF rich-edit text boxes are not designed to produce/edit HTML.

Comment: @Spawn , I prefer a free , but if there is a good not free, I have to use.

Comment: @Brannon, no need to use HTML , just allow ease of creating and editing equations.

Comment: WPF-Math is now active. I've forked it to GitHub, contacted the original author and got his blessing. See https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math